# Problem testing RBAC permissions, using optional resourceName

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I am trying to check if I set permissions correctly in a role `developer` to get a specific pod called `dark-blue-app`. The role is:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-13T00:24:53Z"
  name: developer
  namespace: blue
  resourceVersion: "4099"
  uid: ac280f91-da44-4a33-aa5e-3b4176f8a3a6
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - dark-blue-app
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - list
  - create
  - delete
```

And I have a `rolebinding` set to it (`dev-user-binding`).

Testing to see if I have right permissions I executed:

```
kubectl auth can-i get pod -n=blue --as developer
```

Which returned `YES`

But, if I try to run to check specifically for `dark-blue-app`:

```
kubectl auth can-i get pod dark-blue-app -n=blue --as dev-user
```

Returns:

```
error: you must specify two or three arguments: verb, resource, and optional resourceName
```

**EDIT:**

This is dev-user-binding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-13T01:14:15Z"
  name: dev-user-binding
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1522"
  uid: 29d2092e-fbb6-454c-8a7e-b83f3158abb2
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: developer
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: dev-user
```

Comment: try kubectl auth can-i get pod/dark-blue-app -n=blue --as dev-user

Comment: Right, that was what I did and worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @fg78nc it was fixed by changing the command:

```
kubectl auth can-i get pod dark-blue-app -n=blue --as dev-user
```

To:

```
kubectl auth can-i get pod/dark-blue-app -n=blue --as dev-user
```